# SQL Server - Selecting Frequent Records Within Time Frame

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to select all the records where one column has the same records and the datetime is within 5 minutes of each other. I manage a ticketing system, and I am trying to view all similar tickets created within a 5-minute time frame. See below for a sample dataset:

```
|ID |Subject    |CreatedDateTime    |
-------------------------------------
|1  |A          |2020-09-28 11:01:00|
|2  |A          |2020-09-28 11:02:00|
|3  |A          |2020-09-28 11:03:00|
|4  |A          |2020-09-28 11:03:09|
|5  |A          |2020-09-28 11:04:52|
|6  |A          |2020-09-28 11:15:00|
|7  |B          |2020-09-28 11:20:00|
|8  |B          |2020-09-28 11:20:00|
|9  |B          |2020-09-28 11:20:00|
```

My goal is to only select records 1-5, because 5 the same Subject and they were all created within 5 minutes of each other. 6-10 should not be selected because the amount of Subjects is not great enough, or it is outside the specified time frame.

Below is a test query that I have so far, yet it does not take into account the 5-minute range (I am only looking back 1 week, hence that clause):

```
SELECT Subject,COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
WHERE CreatedDateTime > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY Subject
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Is there any way to only see similar records in a close time frame? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could peak ahead and behind for each record, find the time difference in minutes, and then retain only records which are connected to at least one other record within a span of 5 minutes:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           DATEDIFF(minute,
               LAG(CreatedDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Subject
                                          ORDER BY CreatedDateTime),
               CreatedDateTime) AS LagCreatedDateTime,
           DATEDIFF(minute,
               CreatedDateTime,
               LEAD(CreatedDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Subject
                                           ORDER BY CreatedDateTime))
                AS LeadCreatedDateTime
    FROM TableName
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE LagCreatedDateTime <= 5 OR LeadCreatedDateTime <= 5;
```

See the demo link below for an example running with your sample data.

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the response. When I run this query (after updating the TableName), I am getting a syntax error at Line 9 near the keyword 'AS'. Additionally, when I comment out everything for the LeadCreatedDateTime, I am getting several results that only have one record in the database. When I added `AND Subject IN (previousQueryFromAbove)` it is better, but there are still some standalone Subjects that only appear once.

Comment: @AndrewDraper Apologies, I had a missing parenthesis in there.  Please try the corrected updated answer, which seems to be working in the demo link above.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I ended up adding the query in my previous comment to do some extra filtering, but what you listed is pretty much exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!

Comment: elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to group records which are within 5 minutes of each other then you can use a recursive query to "group" date ranges as follows

```
with data
  as (select *,row_number() over(partition by subject order by createddatetime) as rnk
        from t
        )
    ,cte
    as(select id,subject,createddatetime as begin_date, createddatetime,cast(1 as int) as grp
         from data
       where rnk=1  
       union all
       select b.id
             ,b.subject
             ,b.createddatetime
             ,case when datediff(minute,a.createddatetime,b.createddatetime) > 5 then 
                    b.createddatetime
                   else
                    a.createddatetime
               end as createddatetime
             ,case when datediff(minute,a.createddatetime,b.createddatetime) > 5 then 
                    a.grp+1
                   else
                    a.grp
               end as grp  
         from cte a
         join t b
           on a.id+1=b.id
          and a.subject=b.subject 
       )
     select * from cte  order by 1

 +----+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----+
| id | subject |       begin_date        |     createddatetime     | grp |
+----+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----+
|  1 | A       | 2020-09-28 11:01:00.000 | 2020-09-28 11:01:00.000 |   1 |
|  2 | A       | 2020-09-28 11:02:00.000 | 2020-09-28 11:01:00.000 |   1 |
|  3 | A       | 2020-09-28 11:03:00.000 | 2020-09-28 11:01:00.000 |   1 |
|  4 | A       | 2020-09-28 11:03:09.000 | 2020-09-28 11:01:00.000 |   1 |
|  5 | A       | 2020-09-28 11:04:52.000 | 2020-09-28 11:01:00.000 |   1 |
|  6 | A       | 2020-09-28 11:15:00.000 | 2020-09-28 11:15:00.000 |   2 |
|  6 | A       | 2020-09-28 11:17:00.000 | 2020-09-28 11:17:00.000 |   2 |
|  7 | B       | 2020-09-28 11:20:00.000 | 2020-09-28 11:20:00.000 |   1 |
|  8 | B       | 2020-09-28 11:20:00.000 | 2020-09-28 11:20:00.000 |   1 |
|  9 | B       | 2020-09-28 11:20:00.000 | 2020-09-28 11:20:00.000 |   1 |
+----+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----+
```

db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7fabc2d2753c2ab01bb40f58d82bf222

Comment: Hi George, I edited the query you gave me with the correct tablename but I do not know if this is returning the correct results. In your results listed above, IDs 6-9 are returning, but record 6 is not within 5 minutes of another record, and there are only 3 records for 7-9, so therefore should not return

Comment: You would find that the query i have is grouped by the (subject,grp) combo. Eg:(A,1) groups together records ids 1-5 as they all fall under the first 5 minutes from 11:01 hrs. (A,2) groups together the next set of 5 minute intervals which is (11:15,11:17)